# Monitor Row for Changes ("Last Updated" Column)

Tags: vba, excel

I need a way to monitor a row in excel and update a cell at the end of the row for today's date if anything in the row changes.

For Example:

I have a spreadsheet where projects are listed per row.  I have a column that lists the "last updated" date, I need that date to update whenever any content in that entire row changes.

Columns A:F are the content
Column G is the "Last Updated" cell.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: This can be easily achieved by simple VBA. However, i think you want a non-vba solution. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

As your tag suggests *excel-vba*, I would assume VBA is also an option :

1st you need to see if the current changed row or range is inside your acceptable range ($A:$F), so we use Intersect method.
If yes, in the same sheet, same row but column 'G' enter todays date.

Here is the vba code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("$A:$F"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = Date
    End If
End Sub
```

Enter this code inside the same sheet module (in vba editor) where you would want to implement the functionality. Thats it... :)

**Edit:** This dosen't help much without protection because any one can again change the last edited date. But, thats a totally different question.

Comment: Glad this helped, if you are good with this solution, please accept the answer as solved. And, yes, welcome to SO, happy new year.